# Rounding of timestamp to nearest second

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've got a table containing timestamp values, and I want to round each of these values to the nearest second, but I can't get it work properly.

My test data and approaches so far:

```
with v_data as
 (select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.00000000',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
         to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
    from dual
  union all
  select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.46300000',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
         to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
    from dual
  union all
  select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.50000000',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
         to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:31',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
    from dual
  union all
  select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.56300000',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
         to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:31',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected

    from dual
  union all
  select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.99999999',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
         to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:31',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
    from dual)
select v1.base_val,
       v1.expected,
       v1.base_val + (0.5 / 86400) solution_round,
       cast(v1.base_val as date) as solution_cast,
       extract(second from v1.base_val) - trunc(extract(second from v1.base_val)) fractional_seconds,
       v1.base_val -
       (extract(second from v1.base_val) - trunc(extract(second from v1.base_val))) / 86400 solution_add
  from v_data v1
```

All my solutions have a flaw:

- solution_round always rounds up
- solution_cast works up to 11gR1, but in 11gR2, it always rounds down (cause: Oracle changed the behaviour - it now truncates instead of rounding, see https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2242066 )
- solution_add returns 10:49:29 instead of 10:49:31 for the last three rows

I *guess* solution_add should work, and I just made some stupid mistake :-)

**EDIT:**

Ben's solution (see below) works for me, but relying on to_char(timestamp, 'FF') seems to be dangerous - the number of digits returned depends on the definition of the timestamp.

I'm using to_char(timestamp, 'FF3') instead, which seems to return milliseconds reliably.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some parentheses there? `x + 0.5 / 86400 == x + (0.5 / 86400)`

Comment: Strictly speaking, the parentheses aren't necessary, because the precedence of / is higher than that of + . But I've added them nevertheless to make this clearer, thanks.

Comment: ...yes, that's what I meant. 0.5 / 86400 doesn't make any sense (`x + 0.5 / 86400 ~= x + 0.0000058`). Shouldn't it be `( x + 0.5 ) / 86400`?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. I want to add half a second (0.5 / (24*60*60), truncate it and use that (kind of "poor man's rounding")

Comment: Ok, I thought we were talking about Unix timestamps. Oracle's version sounds pretty screwed-up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My preferred method would be to use a CASE statement and the fact that you can convert the fractional seconds to a number, i.e.:

```
select base_val, expected
     , to_timestamp(to_char(base_val,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss')
        + case when to_number(to_char(base_val, 'FF8')) >= 50000000
                    then interval '1' second
               else interval '0' second
          end as solution_add
  from v_data
```

This removes the fractional seconds. Then works out whether the fractional seconds portion of your TIMESTAMP is 0.5 seconds, or more. If so then add a second, otherwise don't.

I find it a lot clearer and easier to understand what's going on. It returns the following:

```
with v_data as
 (select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.00000000',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
         to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
    from dual
  union all
  select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.46300000',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
         to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
    from dual
  union all
  select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.50000000',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
         to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:31',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
    from dual
  union all
  select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.56300000',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
         to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:31',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
    from dual
  union all
  select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.99999999',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
         to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:31',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
    from dual
         )
select base_val, expected
     , to_timestamp(to_char(base_val, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss')
        + case when to_number(to_char(base_val, 'FF8')) >= 50000000
                    then interval '1' second
               else interval '0' second
          end as solution_add
  from v_data;

BASE_VAL                     EXPECTED                     SOLUTION_ADD
---------------------------- ---------------------------- ----------------------------
10-DEC-12 10.49.30.000000000 10-DEC-12 10.49.30.000000000 10-DEC-12 10.49.30.000000000
10-DEC-12 10.49.30.463000000 10-DEC-12 10.49.30.000000000 10-DEC-12 10.49.30.000000000
10-DEC-12 10.49.30.500000000 10-DEC-12 10.49.31.000000000 10-DEC-12 10.49.31.000000000
10-DEC-12 10.49.30.563000000 10-DEC-12 10.49.31.000000000 10-DEC-12 10.49.31.000000000
10-DEC-12 10.49.30.999999990 10-DEC-12 10.49.31.000000000 10-DEC-12 10.49.31.000000000
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the precision returned by to_char(timestamp, 'FF') depends on the definition of the timestamp - e.g. for a timestamp(3), it will return thousandths of a second, and the comparison will not work as expected. But for my data, it's ok.

Comment: It should have really been FF8 @FrankSchmitt. As you note it makes no difference in your case but it's best to specify.

Answer (score 3):

your final approach works (solution_add) its just that you used - instead of +. the 11g behavious is due to a bug fix (in 10g and below, plsql used to behave as "trunc" when cast was used, whereas SQL behaved as round. Oracle decided PLSQL was right, and changed 11g accordingly.

i.e. use:

```
   v1.base_val +
   (extract(second from v1.base_val) - trunc(extract(second from v1.base_val))) / 86400 solution_add
```

though i'd probably specify it explicitly to take away the implicit conversion from timestamp to date (avoiding the dodgy cast())

```
to_date(to_char(v1.base_val, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')+
       (( extract(second from v1.base_val) - trunc(extract(second from v1.base_val))) / 86400)
```

eg:

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production

SQL> with v_data as
  2   (select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.00000000',
  3                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
  4           to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30',
  5                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
  6      from dual
  7    union all
  8    select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.46300000',
  9                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
 10           to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30',
 11                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
 12      from dual
 13    union all
 14    select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.50000000',
 15                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
 16           to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:31',
 17                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
 18      from dual
 19    union all
 20    select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.56300000',
 21                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
 22           to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:31',
 23                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
 24      from dual
 25    union all
 26    select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.99999999',
 27                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
 28           to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:31',
 29                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
 30      from dual)
 31  select v1.base_val,
 32         v1.expected,
 33         v1.base_val +
 34         (extract(second from v1.base_val) - trunc(extract(second from v1.base_val))) / 86400 solution_add,
 35         to_date(to_char(v1.base_val, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')+
 36         (( extract(second from v1.base_val) - trunc(extract(second from v1.base_val))) / 86400) solution_add2
 37    from v_data v1;

BASE_VAL                  EXPECTED                  SOLUTION_ADD              SOLUTION_ADD2
------------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------- -------------------------
10-dec-12 10:49:30000     10-dec-12 10:49:30000     10-dec-2012 10:49:30      10-dec-2012 10:49:30
10-dec-12 10:49:30463     10-dec-12 10:49:30000     10-dec-2012 10:49:30      10-dec-2012 10:49:30
10-dec-12 10:49:30500     10-dec-12 10:49:31000     10-dec-2012 10:49:31      10-dec-2012 10:49:31
10-dec-12 10:49:30563     10-dec-12 10:49:31000     10-dec-2012 10:49:31      10-dec-2012 10:49:31
10-dec-12 10:49:30999     10-dec-12 10:49:31000     10-dec-2012 10:49:31      10-dec-2012 10:49:31




SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

SQL> with v_data as
  2   (select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.00000000',
  3                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
  4           to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30',
  5                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
  6      from dual
  7    union all
  8    select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.46300000',
  9                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
 10           to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30',
 11                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
 12      from dual
 13    union all
 14    select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.50000000',
 15                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
 16           to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:31',
 17                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
 18      from dual
 19    union all
 20    select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.56300000',
 21                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
 22           to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:31',
 23                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
 24      from dual
 25    union all
 26    select to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:30.99999999',
 27                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss.FF8') base_val,
 28           to_timestamp('2012-12-10 10:49:31',
 29                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') expected
 30      from dual)
 31  select v1.base_val,
 32         v1.expected,
 33         v1.base_val +
 34         (extract(second from v1.base_val) - trunc(extract(second from v1.base_val))) / 86400 solution_add,
 35         to_date(to_char(v1.base_val, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')+
 36         (( extract(second from v1.base_val) - trunc(extract(second from v1.base_val))) / 86400) solution_add2
 37    from v_data v1;

BASE_VAL                  EXPECTED                  SOLUTION_ADD              SOLUTION_ADD2
------------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------- -------------------------
10-dec-12 10:49:30000     10-dec-12 10:49:30000     10-dec-12 10:49:30        10-dec-12 10:49:30
10-dec-12 10:49:30463     10-dec-12 10:49:30000     10-dec-12 10:49:30        10-dec-12 10:49:30
10-dec-12 10:49:30500     10-dec-12 10:49:31000     10-dec-12 10:49:31        10-dec-12 10:49:31
10-dec-12 10:49:30563     10-dec-12 10:49:31000     10-dec-12 10:49:31        10-dec-12 10:49:31
10-dec-12 10:49:30999     10-dec-12 10:49:31000     10-dec-12 10:49:31        10-dec-12 10:49:31
```

Comment: FYI: I've revoked my acceptance and accepted Ben's solution instead, since IMO it's clearer and easier to understand, but I've upvoted yours - thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I am very, very late to this discussion but just in case someone searches, there is a one-line answer to this question:

First CAST to a TIMESTAMP(0) - it has no fractional seconds so they will be rounded.
Then CAST the result to a DATE

```
alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
with data as (select sys_extract_utc(localtimestamp) ts from dual)
select ts, cast(cast(ts as timestamp(0)) as date) dte
from data;
```

Comment: You might be late, but that solution is just brilliant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting to_date and doing the rounding at that point?

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0260__Date-Timestamp-Functions/RoundingtotheNearestMinute.htm

You should then be able to convert to timestamp.

Obviously change the 'MI' on line 3 to 'SS'

---UPDATE---
Casting to a date will round to the nearest second as the DATE datatype has a precision of seconds, so cast to a date and then cast to a timestamp:

> to_timestamp(CAST( '2012-12-10 10:49:30.99999999' AS DATE))

Comment: Apparently there is no SS option when rounding because CAST(timestamp AS DATE) will automatically round to the nearest second.

Comment: This doesn't work on 11gR2, since CAST() now truncates instead of rounding (see solution_cast in my question)

Comment: Interestingly it appears that this is a bug that was fixed. CAST will truncate as of 11gR2, you need to use TO_DATE:http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/functions/to_date Let me know if this works and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's unclear to me what exactly you are suggesting - that I use to_date(timestamp) ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20884/discussion-between-twoleggedhorse-and-frank-schmitt)

Answer (score -1):

This is T-SQL (not sure if it works on Oracle)

```
DECLARE @tblTime TABLE (ID INT, myTime DATETIME2);
INSERT INTO @tblTime SELECT 1, GETDATE()

SELECT  myTime
    , CONVERT( DATETIME2, CONVERT( VARCHAR, DATEADD( SECOND, CASE WHEN DATEPART( MS, myTime) >= 500 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END, myTime ), 20), 20 ) AS timeRounded
FROM    @tblTime
```

Comment: That will not work at all (even when removing the table variables)

Comment: Sorry, but that sure works with T-SQL, I tried it. But anyhow, you can get idea on how to get it to work from it. Basically, it is a use a CASE statement to determine if to add a second or not. And use a rounding mechanism (with the CONVERT/CAST with a format that strip the mmmm part out of the original date and adjust the second base on the adjustment from the CASE.